# Need help to Convert SQL to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

i need help, i need to convert the following query from SQL to LINQ.

and use it in my mvc view

```
select b.ID from LibraryTable a
left join User b on a.UserNumber=b.UserNumber
```

Comment: It's very hard *not* to find any meaningful hits when looking for LINQ + outer join. Go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

From msdn: [Left Outer Joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)

```
var query = from t in LibraryTable
            join u in User on t.UserNumber equals u.UserNumber into tu
            from d in tu.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { Id = u == null ? 0 : u.ID };
```

However, you say you want a left join, but only select something from the right table. This example will just return 0 for anything in LibraryTable that does not have a User record. You may want to consider also selecting something from the left table.  To do that, add a new property in the anonymous type in the select.